# MongoDB, how to manage user related records

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently trying to learn Node.js and Mongoodb by building the server side of a web application which should manage insurance documents for the insurance agent.

So let's say i'm the user, I sign in, then I start to add my customers and their insurances.

**So I have 2 collection related, Customers and Insurances.**

I have one more collection to store the users login data, let's call it **Users**.

I don't want the new users to see and modify the customers and the insurances of other users.

**How can I "divide" every user related record, so that each user can work only with his data?**

I figured out I can actually add to every record, the _id of the one user who created the record.

For example I login as myself, I got my Id  "001", I could add one field with this value in every customer and insurance.

In that way I could filter every query with this code.

**Would it be a good idea?** In my opinion this filtering is a waste of processing power for mongoDB.

If someone has any idea of a solution, or even a link to an article about it, it would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a general permissions problem than just a MongoDB question. Also, without knowing more about your schemas it's hard to give specific advice.

However, here are some approaches:

**1) Embed sub-documents**

Since MongoDB is a document store allowing you to store arbitrary JSON-like objects, you could simply store the customers and licenses wholly inside each user object. That way querying for a user would return their customers and licenses as well.

**2) Denormalise**

Common practice for NoSQL databases is to denormalise related data (ie. duplicate the data). This might include embedding a sub-document that is a partial representation of your customers/licenses/whatever inside your user document. This has the similar benefit to the above solution in that it eliminates additional queries for sub-documents. It also has the same drawbacks of requiring more care to be taken for preserving data integrity.

**3) Reference with foreign key**

This is a more traditionally relational approach, and is basically what you're suggesting in your question. Depending on whether you want the reference to be bi-directional (both documents reference each other) or uni-directional (one document references the other) you can either store the user's ID as a foreign `user_id` field, or store an array of `customer_ids` and `insurance_ids` in the user document. In relational parlance this is sometimes described to as "has many" or "belongs to" (the user *has many* customers, the customer *belongs to* a user).

Comment: Ok, I figured out I can keep un-related collections of insurances and customers, and then embed part of each record into the related user document. In that way one I get the user, i'll get some info about the related data, like the references for his customers, and use them to retrieve the full data only if I need them